# How do I link the library correctly using cmake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have laid out my project directory below,so when I do cmake build I get a linker error which I wasn't able to figure out. I get a linker error that LIBD cannot be found, although LIBB is successfully formed and APP executable only needs LIBB why is it throwing a linker error that it needs LIBD when trying to build APP?

```
|---CMakeLists.txt <==== add_subdirectory(source) , add_subdirectory(apps)

|---build

|---include
    |---a.h
    |---b.h

|---apps|   
    |---CMakeLists.txt
    |---apps.cpp              1] target_link_libraries(APP PUBLIC LIBB)   <==== linker error 
                                                                                 LIBD not found
  
|---source
|   |---CMakeLists.txt  ===>  1]link_directories(PATH TO LIBD)
                              2]target_link_libraries(LIBA public LIBC) <== successful
                              3]target_link_libraries (LIBB public LIBA LIBD) <== successful

    |---a.cpp
    |---b.cpp

|---lib
|   |---LIBD    <===== static library
```

Comment: This is pretty confusing. Where is the LIBD target defined? Is it in scope at the moment you issue the `target_link_libraries` call?

Comment: @Botje LIBD is a static library

Comment: add_library(a.cpp b.cpp ${LIBD} )

Comment: @AdabH I need both LIBA and LIBB  not the source files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_directories` is scoped to the file containing it, in your case `source/CMakeLists.txt`, so `apps/CMakeLists.txt` does not know where to find LIBD.

You should create an IMPORTED CMake target in the main CMakeLists.txt instead and link to that where you need it:

```
add_library(LIBD IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(LIBD PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION lib/LIBD.a)
```

Or, alternatively, you could repeat the `link_directories` statement in your `apps/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion, but  i have question for you, LIBB has been successduly build while APP just depends on LIBB , Why is it complaining that doesn't find LIBD. I mean isn't LIBB standalone static library.

Comment: Yes I read that botje, sorry if I am not understanding,  why does apps/CMakeLists.txt need to find LIBD , when it just depends on LIBB, am I missing something?

Comment: Adding LIBD to the PUBLIC interface of LIBB makes it a transitive dependency. Link it as PRIVATE if you do not want that.

Comment: Hi Botje,Making PUBLIC to PRIVATE didn't help but making changes to the main CMakeLists.txt as you suggested helped.